# Calling a method from another class (using Turtle)

Tags: java, methods, static-methods, private-members

I'm trying to draw blue spots at some (x,y) coordinates using Turtle. For the assignment, we have a package with two classes in it. The main class Regression.java (which I'm coding in) and the second class Turtle.java. I'm not suppose to change anything within the Turtle class, just access its methods to draw the points.

I'm successfully able to set the scale using the format:

```
Turtle.setScale(600/xMax);
```

The method for setScale is:

```
public static void setScale(double scale) {
    Turtle.scale = scale;
}
```

However, when I try setting the color to blue using the same format:

```
Turtle.setColor(Color.BLUE);
```

I get a null pointer exception.

Here is the setColor() method from the Turtle class:

```
public static void setColor(Color color) {
    foreground = color;
    offscreen.setColor(foreground);
}
```

foreground is initialized inside the Turtle class as:

```
private static Color foreground = Color.black;
```

I don't understand why one accessor would work and the second would fail. Is it because foreground is a private variable? If so, how can I use Turtle.setColor() without going into Turtle and changing its setColor method?

Thanks

Comment: Well it shouldn't fail. The fact that it is private doesn't matter because you are using a public method that has  access to the private accessor. What error are you getting ?

Comment: Its showing a null pointer exception. It's being thrown at the line in Turtle : " foreground = color; "

Comment: What @alainlompo just said. Anyways if possible provide the full code of the Turtle class.

Comment: Can you provide a complete example that reproduces the error you are asking about? Be sure to include the entire error message and indicate which line causes the error. For some tips on creating a good code example, see [mcve]. (Note that the Turtle class is not standard, so you need to include the relevant code from it as well. Just give enough for your example to compile, not the entire class.)

Comment: @alainlompo  Had the right solution.                                            offscreen needed to be called into existence first in a separate method before setting the color. Setting the color without doing so was causing a null exception. I don't know where  alainlompo  answer went otherwise I would check it off as right. Sorry  alainlompo  I'm new to stackoverflow and still figuring out how to use it. If you see this and repost you're solution I'll mark it as correct. Thanks